# Using filter function to create a variable with common attribute (Leaflet, GeoJSON, jQuery)

Tags: jquery, leaflet, geojson

I have ~70 points with associated properties that are listed in an external geoJSON file. Each point has a value for "year". My goal is to create buttons that you can click to display only points from a given year. For example: clicking the 2013 button would make only the points with "year" = 2013 visible on the map.

Link to my project: https://github.com/erinreiss/mallikaMap/tree/try3

My attempt was to get all the 2013 points in a single variable, like this:

```
var trees2013_3 = L.geoJson(myJson, {filter: year2013get});

function year2013get(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.year === "2013") return true
}
```

Then to be able to operate on that variable like this, where I was trying to experiment by making the button bring all 2013 points down to opacity .1:

```
var toggle2013 = document.getElementById('button2013');
    button2013.onclick = function() {
        console.log('Show 2013 Trees!');
        console.log(trees2013_3);
        $('trees2013_3').animate({"opacity": .1});
    }
```

Instead, I'm getting an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined
>       at Object.year2013get [as filter] (script.js:59)
>       at e.addData (leaflet.js:8)
>       at e.initialize (leaflet.js:8)
>       at new e (leaflet.js:6)
>       at Object.o.geoJson (leaflet.js:8)
>       at script.js:55

Thank you!